# what is SharePoint compliance and how it useful?

Tags: 2013, 2010

What is SharePoint compliance and how it is useful and what are the complaince settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint Compliance  requires to comply users with a specific usage policy, In your SharePoint sites, it consists of :

- **IRM for Document Libraries** : to disallow user copy your document content
- **Record Center and In-Place Holds** : for archiving with 3 Tera content database.
- **Auditing** : to audit any changes occurs in your SharePoint site.
- **Retention or Deletion Policies** : to build retention for the old document based on its using to be archived or deleted.

**Why Compliance?**

It's a boring but mandatory, It can come from a number of reasons. Legal and regulatory requirements, organizational governance or internal and external threats are the main factors for it, however. To make it easier on you, people are using all kinds of technology now to create content, and it's not always the same application used through the content's lifecycle.

**To configure SharePoint Compliance check this:**

- [Configure audit settings for a site collection](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-audit-settings-for-a-site-collection-a9920c97-38c0-44f2-8bcb-4cf1e2ae22d2)
- [Overview of Compliance in SharePoint and Office 365](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/SharePoint-Conference/2014/SPC233)
- [Introduction to Records Management and Compliance](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-Records-Management-and-Compliance-99743e35-335e-4010-a244-be8646beb771)

Comment: Dear 
I waste more time to try to help you  If this is useful for you. Please, don't hesitate to upvote my answer and set it as Answer if it's considered an answer

Comment: Great this also helped me

Comment: Hi what is compliance risk for a sharepoint farm and in which situations it happen?